# How to change Bitlocker password in windows using script?

Tags: python, powershell, vbscript

I am writing a script to change the bitlocker password in windows.

I have found that "manage-bde -changepassword C:"  can be executed to change the password for then bitlocker. If run in command prompt it will ask the user to enter the password and confirm the password. It worked well manually. 
How can I achieve this through python subprocess module or vb script or using the Powershell ?

I have tried following code but it is not working

```
import subprocess
p =subprocess.Popen("manage-bde -changepassword C:", shell = True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("Passw0rd")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate("Passw0rd")
print stdout
```

Error:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.10011

Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070006):

The handle is invalid.
```

Also tried below vb script but still no luck

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run("manage-bde.exe -changepassword C:" ,0,True)
WshShell.SendKeys "P@ssw0rd"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "P@ssw0rd"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: PowerShell: `$Volume = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/CIMV2/Security/MicrosoftVolumeEncryption -ClassName Win32_EncryptableVolume -Filter 'DriveLetter="C:"'; $Protector = (Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $Volume -MethodName GetKeyProtectors -Arguments @{ KeyProtectorType=8 }).VolumeKeyProtectorID[0]; Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $Volume -MethodName ChangePassPhrase -Arguments @{ VolumeKeyProtectorID=$Protector; NewPassphrase='P@ssw0rd' }`

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl  Thanks for your comments. But this not worked in my winodws 10 system where bitlocker is enabled.

Comment: NewProtectorID                         ReturnValue PSComputerName
--------------                         ----------- --------------
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  2150694941

Comment: Above output appears after powershell execution .But password does not changed when i checked

Comment: Is password key protector is only key protector on your BitLocker volume?